# How to SELECT only entrys with MAX(DATE) per TestcaseID and VariantID?

Tags: mysql

I'm currently using a large SELECT statement that gives me all the informations that I need out of multiple tables (performance isnt that great sadly), but what I would like to do is to only show one entry per testcase.foreignID AND variant.idVariant, the one that has the highest plannedtestset.Date

I've tried Group By, without success yet.

```
SELECT testcase.foreignID AS TcID, testcase.foreignOrderNr AS TcOrderNr,testcase.Name AS TcName,variant.Name AS Variant,device.Supplier,plannedtestset.foreignID AS TestSetID,plannedtestset.Date,tester.Name AS Tester,testcaseexecution.Result,testcaseexecution.Comment,sw_version.Version AS SW_Version,hw_version.Version AS HW_Version,testcase.ABP,testtype.Name AS TestType,project.Name AS Project
    FROM mydb.testcaseexecution
    INNER JOIN mydb.testcase
    ON testcaseexecution.Testcase_idTestcase=testcase.idTestcase
    INNER JOIN mydb.plannedtestset
    ON testcaseexecution.PlannedTestSet_idPlannedTestSet=plannedtestset.idPlannedTestSet
    INNER JOIN mydb.device
    ON plannedtestset.Device_idDevice=device.idDevice
    INNER JOIN mydb.variant
    ON device.Variant_idVariant=variant.idVariant
    INNER JOIN mydb.tester
    ON plannedtestset.Tester_idTester=tester.idTester
    INNER JOIN mydb.sw_version
    ON plannedtestset.SW_Version_idSW_Version=sw_version.idSW_Version
    INNER JOIN mydb.testtype
    ON plannedtestset.TestType_idTestType=testtype.idTestType
    INNER JOIN mydb.project
    ON plannedtestset.Project_idProject=project.idProject
    INNER JOIN mydb.hw_version
    ON device.HW_Version_idHW_Version=hw_version.idHW_Version

    WHERE plannedtestset.Date In(
        SELECT Max(plannedtestset.Date)
        FROM mydb.plannedtestset
        GROUP BY testcase.idTestcase
    )
```

Comment: What about enclosing the above as an inner query and have the outer query selecting only one record (i.e. `LIMIT 1`) after sorting OR selecting the MAX(<field>)?

Comment: I dont quite understand, do you mind giving an SELECT statement example?

Comment: Please show sample data.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score -1):

What I meant in my comment is something like this:

```
SELECT .... , MAX(A.plannedtestset.Date),...
  FROM (<your original select>) A ;
```

I would also suggest to add aliasing to the names of the retrieved fields of the inner query.

This is the simples (for you) solution. There are other solutions modifying your original query, but (since performance does not appear to be an issue for you) I would first go in the direction proposed here.